# How to upload a file to another website from my website in meteor?

Tags: file, meteor, upload, meteor-blaze

My application is developed using meteor.But, I want to upload a file from my client side to another web application (Developed by java).

I was trying to implement ajax call. but, I am getting cors error.

**client/upload.js**

```
Template.bulkUserCreation.events({
    'submit form': function (event, template) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var file = template.find('input[type="file"]').files[0];

        var form = event.currentTarget;

        var userUpload = {};

        userUpload.url = Meteor.urlConfig.ADD_TENANT_BULK_USER;
        userUpload.headers['Content-type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
        userUpload.headers.fileSize = file.size;

        var fd = new FormData();

        fd.append('file',file);

        $.ajax({
            url: userUpload.url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: fd,
            headers: userUpload.headers,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false, // Don't process the files
            contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                if(typeof data.error === 'undefined')
                {
                    // Success so call function to process the form
                    alert('Success');
                }
                else
                {
                    // Handle errors here
                    console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                // Handle errors here
                console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
                // STOP LOADING SPINNER
            }
        });
    },
});
```

**Response:**

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.120:8080/*********/_bulk?tenantId=1001. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Please help me. how to get it done.

Comment: hi and welcome to SO, if you provide your code attempts so far then the community are going to be much more inclined to help that than 'give me code' without evidence of effort. That way they can help many more people.

Comment: Hi, I added code in same section.

Comment: So one question, is your Java App server setup to handle CORS? This resource might help: [link](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-add-cors-support-on-the-server-side-in-java-with-jersey/)

Comment: Thanks for your support.

Comment: Using httpd configuration, It's working fine.